# ffmpeg concat removing sound of videos

Tags: video, ffmpeg, encode

I've used this code for merging three videos together with ffmpeg :

```
ffmpeg -y -f concat -safe 0 -i list.txt -c copy done.mp4
```

the `list.txt` contains :

```
file 'first.mp4'
duration 2.5
file 'second.mp4'
duration 20.0
file 'third.mp4'
duration 1.5
```

But the output video doesn't have any sound! I want sound of each one remains on the output.

what code should i use?

Comment: Show the full output of `ffmpeg -i first.mp4 -i second.mp4 -i third.mp4`. It will provide information about each input which is required to give an accurate answer.

Comment: I see you [crossposted this at Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/1390603/ffmpeg-concat-removing-sound-of-videos). Please avoid doing that as it dilutes effort and wastes time.